# Redis: Find keys that exist

Tags: performance, redis, bigdata

We have a list of numbers stored in redis as keys (300 million keys which are 10 digit numeric keys).

Our users give us a list of about 1 million numbers and expect that we get out a subset of these numbers that do not exist in redis as keys. The expectation is to get the result in sub second and we have been trying to use Redis for the same.

Initially it looked like the right way to go (using EXISTS), but now we are questioning if there are better ways to get to the resultant without looping through these numbers and creating the subset.

Could someone please let us know how we could do this efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

Old question I know, but I thought it deserved a fuller answer.

The problem with getting all the keys from redis and then doing the containment test is that you have to pull the 300m keys from redis for every check, or keep a "local" copy of those keys which defeats the point in redis.

Instead of taking the data to the processing, much better to take the processing to the data.

You can use redis [sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets) and let redis do the set diffing.

Using python-redis here, but obviously the execution of redis could be done from any language.

```py
import os, base64, time, redis

r = redis.Redis()

def create_keys(n, size=10):
    data = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(n * size))
    return [data[i:i+size] for i in range(0, n * size, size)]

if not r.exists('ref_keys'):
    for _ in range(3):
        r.sadd('ref_keys', *create_keys(1*10**6))
print('{} keys in reference key set'.format(r.scard('ref_keys')))
existing_keys = r.srandmember('ref_keys', number=50*10**3)
keys_to_check = existing_keys + create_keys(50*10**3)
start = time.time()
try:
    r.sadd('check_ref', *keys_to_check)
    missing = r.sdiff('check_ref', 'ref_keys')
finally:
    r.delete('check_ref')
print('number of missing keys: {}, time taken {:0.3f}s'.format(len(missing), time.time() - start))
```

(Most of the code here (and time) is spent creating the test case.)

Only the checked 1m keys have to be transferred, rather than all 300m.

Note: due to memory my `ref_keys` set is only has 30m keys and the containment test took 3s. `SDIFF` has "Time complexity: O(N) where N is the total number of elements in all given sets." so I suspect you would struggle to get the time to below a second on commodity hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should avoid looping on the user list and use EXISTS for each keys. Redis commands are relatively slow (because of the client/server architecture) as opposed to variable manipulation in a usual language.

One solution I would suggest would require some coding : I would get all the existing keys with KEYS (http://redis.io/commands/keys), then sort the result and the user list.
Then you can implement a fast search to check if the user' keys are in the redis keys.

Actually you might use set in Python, with the difference already coded
http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html
(This is unsorted, but the implementation is a dict, which is a hashtable).

Comment: KEYS should never be used against a production redis instance since it is O(n) complexity and will block other requests while it runs. It will take some time to run on OP's instance since it has 300 million keys.

Comment: it should be used with care, I agree. Speed seems to be too slow for 300M entries too. Maybe a copy of the keys list should be maintained outside Redis to be accessible more rapidly.

Comment: @Pixou, Just the keys with 300 Million entries takes ~12 GB of storage. Keeping this data in Redis and also having the key list outside Redis is going to be a costly affair. Also could you suggest what you mean by "maintained outside Redis to be accessible more rapidly". What technology/datastructure could we use? A reference could help here. Again thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: my point was to try to avoid having one redis call for each key submitted by your user, because a redis call is somewhat costly (TCP socket). Maybe you should stick to redis and try to improve perf, with pipelining (not sure this is feasible). Can you also consider connecting to redis via a unix socket ? However, possible improvement is limited.

Comment: the more I think about it, the more difficult it looks to me. Ecen with optimized datastructures, it takes some time to search, and you have to do it 1M times. Several ideas I have : can you suppose that the 1M keys you receive are sorted (can you ask the user to do it) ? can you have several machines to do this job ? Plus one question: network-wise, getting and processing the 1M keys from the user does take some time (it's 40MB!). Isn't it another big challenge ? Overall, I am not sure this can be done in a centralized way.